# Excel Closing Print Preview triggers Workbook_BeforeClose

Tags: vba, excel

I discovered an issue today with my workbook. I have a basic Workbook_BeforeClose sub saved in ThisWorkbook that is used to reset the workbook appearance, ensure sheets are hidden and make it clean for the next time user interfaces with the Worksheet. I don't think that code is relevant but included it anyway just in case.

*My problem* is that when I close **Print Preview** this code is triggered (which I confirmed with a breakpoint) and it asks me if I want to save my project before it closes it.  Of course, I can hit cancel and prevent the file from closing, but it still runs the rest of the script.  This behavior doesn't seem right and I don't want the users getting confused by it.  Has anyone seen this before, or know of a potential fix?

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
     Dim wshide As Worksheet
     Dim wsa As Worksheet
     Dim CurrWs As Worksheet

     Set CurrWs = Sheets(ActiveSheet.Name)

     For Each wsa In Worksheets
        wsa.Activate
        ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView
        wsa.Range("A1").Select
     Next

     For Each wshide In Sheets(Array("Data", "Tables", "Map"))
        wshide.Visible = xlSheetHidden
     Next

    CurrWs.Activate
End Sub
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Workbook_BeforeClose shouldn't be called when just closing Print Preview, it will only be called if you close Print Preview by closing the whole workbook as well.

You can't call Workbook_BeforeClose from another Macro so that will not trigger it either.

The only way Workbook_BeforeClose can be triggered is by closing the workbook.

Comment: Yes, and that is how I understood it as well which is why I was confused.  Going back and looking at it again, it was my own misreading of the screen.  I thought I was hitting the X to close Print Preview, however, it was the 2013 interface and I should have been hitting the back arrow <- or the Esc key to close it.  I was in fact trying to close Excel.